# why it is required to open google home page from chrome browser to enter search from selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I had a doubt with my code . Why is it required to open a google webpage to search something in selenium .why can't we search directly search from chrome browser. below is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chrome_options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
browser=webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)
page=browser.get('http://www.google.com')
search=browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('aditya')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
```

why is the line page=browser.get('http://www.google.com') required. I am anyways using browser to send keys why is page required?

Comment: if you developed the code, then you should know better why `page=browser.get('http://www.google.com`). SeleniumHQ website has very good documentation. For beginners that is a good place to start.

Comment: I did'nt develop it myself I got it in S.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first instantiate a new browser driver, it is just a blank browser.  You need to navigate to a URL before you can interact with any objects on that page.  In your case, you are trying to do a google search, so you must navigate to the page first before being able to find the search element.

You shouldn't have to assign it to the page variable though.  You should be able to just write:

```
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: then why am I finding name 'q' in browser instead of google page in the code browser.find_element_by_name('q')

Comment: I believe you are still navigating to the google page when your code executes and whatever return value is being placed in page, but that's not being used.  Browser is still on google, so when you do your find element from the browser object, the find_element_by_name('q') is valid.